# How do I calculate on-time delivery when SQL tables aren't one to one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following two tables:

DueDates:

```
DECLARE @DueDates TABLE (
    uniqueln varchar(10),
    ship_dts smalldatetime,
    qty decimal(18,4))
INSERT INTO @DueDates
SELECT '51351621AS','1/1/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/7/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/14/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/21/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/28/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/5/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/10/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/15/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/20/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/25/2013',10
```

PlDetail

```
DECLARE @PlDetail TABLE (
    uniqueln varchar(10),
    shipdate smalldatetime,
    shippedqty decimal(18,4))
INSERT INTO @PlDetail
SELECT '51351621AS','1/1/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/7/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/14/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/21/2013',5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/5/2013',13
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/15/2013',9
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/25/2013',12
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/30/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','2/5/2013',6
```

The shipments in `PlDetail` can be one to one with the orders in the `DueDates` table, but often they are not.

I am trying to calculate an on-time delivery for each `uniqueln` schedule using a `FIFO` method (I cannot change how the data is stored in the tables).  Basically, I want to apply the earliest shipments to the earliest deliveries.

If a shipment qty exceeds the balance in a `DueDates` record, it should have the balance applied to the next scheduled delivery.

The end result should look something like this:

```
uniqueln    ship_dts    qty shipdate    shippedqty  daysLate
51351621AS  1/1/2013    7   1/1/2013    7            0
51351621AS  1/7/2013    7   1/1/2013    3           -6
51351621AS  1/7/2013    7   1/7/2013    4            0
51351621AS  1/14/2013   7   1/7/2013    6           -7
51351621AS  1/14/2013   7   1/14/2013   1            0
51351621AS  1/21/2013   7   1/14/2013   7           -7
51351621AS  1/28/2013   7   1/14/2013   2           -14
51351621AS  1/28/2013   7   1/21/2013   5           -7
V4351621AS  1/5/2013    10  1/5/2013    10           0
V4351621AS  1/10/2013   10  1/5/2013    3           -5
V4351621AS  1/10/2013   10  1/15/2013   7            5
V4351621AS  1/15/2013   10  1/15/2013   2            0
V4351621AS  1/15/2013   10  1/25/2013   8           10
V4351621AS  1/20/2013   10  1/25/2013   4            5
V4351621AS  1/20/2013   10  1/30/2013   6           10
V4351621AS  1/25/2013   10  1/30/2013   4            5
V4351621AS  1/25/2013   10  2/5/2013    6           11
```

I know how to group the `PlDetail` shipments strictly by date so any shipment that falls on or before the next due date is grouped together, but it HAS to factor in the scheduled qty vs the shipped qty.

I don't want to create a cursor and cycle through the shipment records, but I can if this type of join won't work.  However, I believe it is possible, but I am not sure how to group or join the tables.

It sounds like SQL Server 2012 has some new methods that will make this easier, but right now I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and have to keep it that way for the near future.

What is the best way to approach this?  Is a cursor really the only way?

**UPDATE:**
This is what I have added so far.  The end result is a table showing the from and to qty and ship_dts for each uniqueln

```
WITH DSeq AS (
   SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
      Seq = Row_Number() OVER (partition by uniqueln ORDER BY ship_dts),
      D.UNIQUELN,
      D.SHIP_DTS,
      SchBal = (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SUM(B.Qty) FROM @DueDates B WHERE b.SHIP_DTS<= D.SHIP_DTS AND b.UNIQUELN=d.UNIQUELN ORDER BY d.SHIP_DTS)
   FROM @DueDates D
   GROUP BY UNIQUELN,D.QTY,D.UNIQUELN,D.SHIP_DTS
   ORDER BY D.UNIQUELN, D.SHIP_DTS
)
--SELECT * FROM DSeq
, Slices AS (
   SELECT
      LN = D.UNIQUELN,
      FromQty = COALESCE(N.SchBal,0),
      ToQty = D.SchBal,
      D.SHIP_DTS
   FROM
      DSeq D
      LEFT OUTER JOIN DSeq N
         ON D.Seq -1 = N.Seq AND D.UNIQUELN=N.UNIQUELN
)
SELECT * FROM Slices
```

**CURSOR APPROACH:**

As has been stated, the best approach might be a cursor.  Hopefully someone has a join method that will meet all the needs, but until then we are using a cursor.

In case someone is looking for a solution to this with a cursor approach, the code below is how we have done it.  The user selects a date range and it produces the results.  Please note that you HAVE to run the cursor for ALL records of the `uniqueln` even if they shipped prior to the selected date range, otherwise the `FIFO` application of shipments will be wrong.

```
DECLARE @startdate smalldatetime, @endDate smalldatetime

DECLARE @OnTime TABLE (Uniqueln varchar(10),DueQty int,dueDate smalldatetime,shipDate smalldatetime,shipQty int DEFAULT 0,daysLate int,balQty int)


DECLARE @uniqln1 varchar(10),@toQty int, @dueDate smalldatetime,@bQty int
DECLARE @uniqln2 varchar(10),@shipQty int, @shipDate smalldatetime

DECLARE ot_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT uniqueln,qty,ship_dts,qty
    FROM @DueDates 
    ORDER BY uniqueln,ship_dts 
OPEN ot_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM ot_cursor INTO @uniqln1,@toQty,@dueDate,@bQty

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE s_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR
    SELECT Uniqueln,shippedqty,shipdate
        FROM @PlDetail p
        WHERE uniqueln = @uniqln1
        ORDER BY 3
    OPEN s_cursor ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM s_cursor INTO @uniqln2,@shipQty,@shipDate
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @OnTime(Uniqueln,DueQty,dueDate,shipDate,shipQty,daysLate,balQty)
        SELECT @uniqln1,@toQty,@dueDate,@shipDate,CASE WHEN @bQty>@shipQty THEN @shipQty ELSE @bQty END,DATEDIFF(d,@dueDate,@shipDate),CASE WHEN @bQty>@shipQty THEN @bQty-@shipQty ELSE 0 END
        SET @bQty=@bQty-@shipQty
        IF @bQty < 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @shipQty = -@bQty 
            FETCH NEXT FROM ot_cursor INTO @uniqln1,@toQty,@dueDate,@bQty
        END
        ELSE 
        IF @bQty =0
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @shipQty = @bQty
            FETCH NEXT FROM s_cursor INTO @uniqln2,@shipQty,@shipDate
        END
    END
    CLOSE s_cursor
    DEALLOCATE s_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ot_cursor INTO @uniqln1,@toQty,@dueDate,@bQty
END
CLOSE ot_cursor
DEALLOCATE ot_cursor

SELECT * FROM @OnTime 
    WHERE shipDate BETWEEN @startdate AND @endDate
    ORDER BY Uniqueln,dueDate
```

Comment: How large are these tables in reality?

Comment: @NickVaccaro potentially thousands to millions of records in each.  However, I can force the on-time to a subset if required (e.g. a specific customer, a restricted date range [last 12 months], a specific sales order [with a collection of uniquelns]).  Generally, the on-time from two years ago is irrelevant.  In any case, the tables are not likely to be under 1000 for very long.

Comment: It may be important to note that while the tables contain hundreds of thousands of records, there should be less than 500 records for any given uniqueln (probably less then 50 and in many cases less than 10).

Comment: @davids What does your query look like right now?

Comment: @Kyle I have a query I have created using the actual tables and it produces results, but they are not valid.  I will post it so you can see.

Comment: @davids Can the initial shipment for an order contains less than the ordered amount? If so, does the next shipment apply to the remaining balance?

Comment: The initial shipment can contain less or more than the initial scheduled amount up to the total scheduled amount.  The only requirement is that the total shipped qty does not exceed the total ordered qty regardless of how few or how many shipments are made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried putting something together using CTEs and a pidgin cross join between the tables.  (don't ask, it was ugly)

Anywho, after a bit of [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652511/sql-server-2008-using-sum-overorder-by), and knowing how large the tables are, I feel pretty safe answering this with... *drumroll*... use a cursor.  It'll be ugly and slow, but the logic will make much more sense on paper.  There's a lot to be said about maintainable code...

Update: Going on vacation.  Here's what I was playing with.

```
DECLARE @DueDates TABLE (
    uniqueln varchar(10),
    ship_dts smalldatetime,
    qty decimal(18,4))
INSERT INTO @DueDates
SELECT '51351621AS','1/1/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/7/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/14/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/21/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/28/2013',7
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/5/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/10/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/15/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/20/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/25/2013',10


DECLARE @PlDetail TABLE (
    uniqueln varchar(10),
    shipdate smalldatetime,
    shippedqty decimal(18,4))
INSERT INTO @PlDetail
SELECT '51351621AS','1/1/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/7/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/14/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT '51351621AS','1/21/2013',5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/5/2013',13
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/15/2013',9
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/25/2013',12
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','1/30/2013',10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V4351621AS','2/5/2013',6



; WITH DueDates AS 
(
    SELECT b.*
    FROM @DueDates a
    JOIN @DueDates b
        ON a.uniqueln = b.uniqueln
        AND b.ship_dts >= a.ship_dts
)
, PlDetail AS
(
    SELECT b.*
    FROM @PlDetail a
    JOIN @PlDetail b
        ON a.uniqueln = b.uniqueln
        AND b.shipdate >= a.shipdate
)
SELECT a.uniqueln
    , SUM(a.qty) AS ordered_running_total
    , SUM(b.shippedqty) AS shipped_running_total
    , a.ship_dts
    , b.shipdate
    , SUM(b.shippedqty) - SUM(a.qty) AS leftover_running_total
FROM DueDates a
JOIN PlDetail b
    ON a.uniqueln = b.uniqueln
    AND a.ship_dts >= b.shipdate
GROUP BY a.uniqueln, a.ship_dts, b.shipdate
HAVING SUM(a.qty) <= SUM(b.shippedqty)
ORDER BY a.uniqueln, a.ship_dts, b.shipdate
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. There really isn't another way?  What does the size of the table have to do with it since the results will be filtered?  Or, are you saying that even with 500 records, anything other than a cursor won't work well?

Comment: From what I understood, 500 records per "uniqueln" at x number of uniquelns makes potentially a metric ****ton of rows.  Since you're basically cross joining the table onto itself, then onto the second table, also cross joined to itself... TLDR - a query that could take 1 second on 100 rows takes 10,000 seconds on 10,000 rows.

Comment: If I force a date restriction (e.g. last 30 days), or an order restriction (e.g. all deliveries for order X), then there should be under 1,000 schedules and the same on shipments (probably under 500 of each) for ALL uniquelns that fall in that window (as opposed to 500 for each uniqueln).  Typically they just need to see how they are doing for on-time in a month, or with an order.

Comment: Updating answer.  Haven't vetted out code - gotta run.  Hopefully it's a good jumping off point though.  Good luck and happy holidays!

Comment: I kept messing but couldn't get the results we needed.  I am not sure we can dynamically apply partial shipments using a join of any type.