# This query 2012 sql server working fine.2008 its not working (Incorrect syntax near 'order'.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ACCOUNTDATE
    ,PROPERTYNAME
    --,SUM(CancellationRooms) AS CANCELLATIONS
    ,SUM(CancellationS) OVER (partition by PROPERTYNAME ORDER BY ACCOUNTDATE,PROPERTYNAME ) AS NOSHOWS
FROM HPATODAY
```

Comment: give me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
        ACCOUNTDATE
        ,PROPERTYNAME
        --,SUM(CancellationRooms) AS CANCELLATIONS
        ,(select SUM(CancellationS) 
from HPATODAY a 
where a.PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME and a.ACCOUNTDATE<=t.ACCOUNTDATE ) AS NOSHOWS
    FROM HPATODAY t
```

Answer (score 2):

[`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx) Clause with partitions introduced in 2008 R2 version.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652511/sql-server-2008-using-sum-overorder-by) topic to make a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Remove order by and you are good to go

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ACCOUNTDATE
,PROPERTYNAME
--,SUM(CancellationRooms) AS CANCELLATIONS
,SUM(CancellationS) OVER (partition by PROPERTYNAME) AS NOSHOWS FROM HPATODAY
```

Comment: we need order by function in that place, then i will get proper output please help us. any alternate solution for this query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT
        ACCOUNTDATE
        ,PROPERTYNAME
        --,SUM(CancellationRooms) AS CANCELLATIONS
        ,(select SUM(CancellationS) 
from HPATODAY a 
where a.PROPERTYNAME = t.PROPERTYNAME and a.ACCOUNTDATE<=t.ACCOUNTDATE ) AS NOSHOWS
    FROM HPATODAY t