# update row same as row above if condition meet with number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have data like this

```
id      type
1.      a
2.      b
3.      c
4.      c
5.      d
6.      c
7.      c
```

target

```
id   type.    group
1.      a.          1
2.      b.          2
3.      c.          2
4.      c.          2
5.      d.          3
6.      c.          3
7.      c.          3
```

if type c, group value take value from above row.
 i can goal this with loop condition and update but that take to much time because looping update many row

how can i achiev this with single update statement with sql server 2008

Comment: How are you ordering the data?  By `id`?

Comment: yes i ordering the data with id

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
declare @t table (id int primary key, val char(1));
insert into @t values 
       (1, 'a')
     , (2, 'b')
     , (3, 'c')
     , (4, 'c')
     , (5, 'd')
     , (6, 'c')
     , (7, 'c');
select * 
     , sum(case when val = 'c' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp
from @t t 
order by id;

id          val  grp
----------- ---- -----------
1           a    1
2           b    2
3           c    2
4           c    2
5           d    3
6           c    3
7           c    3
```

Follow the link below for a running demo.

### Demo

Comment: Nice answer, but what would happen if a non `c` letter repeated more than once (and admittedly the OP should have told us this) ?

Comment: its error Incorrect syntax near 'order' with sql server 2008

Comment: @MuhammadDVikar Runs just fine on my server

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if a non c letter repeated more than once, its belong to diffrent group. if e repeated twice from the data above the group will 4 and 5 order by id

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'order'. i run from visual studio 2010 and connect  it to sql server 2008 r2. what version your server?

Comment: @MuhammadDVikar Please tell me you are not including the output in the query you are trying to run.  Can you not recognize a SQL query?

Comment: i not including the output, i copy your query from declaring variable to order by id

Comment: @MuhammadDVikar Don't know what to tell you.  I works for me.

Comment: i try it to with my case table like this. select sum(case when type = 'condition' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as grp from Table

Comment: @MuhammadDVikar Check the above demo link.  You're doing something wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it use sql server 2014, but i use sql server 2008 r2, i think the query not supported on sql server 2008 r2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652511/sql-server-2008-using-sum-overorder-by. i found this, trying to convert your solution with this

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an alternative to the answer given by @palarazzi which may already be sufficient.  This answer is robust to type letters occurring in any amount.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.id AS id1, t1.type AS type1, t2.id AS id2, t2.type AS type2
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.type <> 'c') OR
            (t1.id > t2.id AND t1.type = 'c' AND t2.type <> 'c')
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT id1, type2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY id2 DESC) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT
    id1 AS id, type2 AS type,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY type2) [group]
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: I am getting supposed to bump even on repeated.  "if e repeated twice from the data above the group will 4 and 5 order by id"